# Can I pull a remote Git repository and also get the remote's (uncommitted) working changes?

Tags: git

Obviously I could do this using rsync or something but does Git itself have a way to bring uncommitted changes from a remote repo into my local repo? I'm wanting to benchmark some remote changes before committing them. I guess I could just make a branch specifically for this but I thought I'd check.

Comment: Uncommitted work is local to your system. How can you get something that's not committed to the cloud?

Comment: How could a remote repo have uncommitted changes?

Comment: It's remote to my local repository, meaning it shows up when I run `git remote`. Any repository that's not your local repo is "remote" to that repo, so the remote repo can have uncommitted local changes. Not all remote repos are bare.

Comment: you can just copy  repo folder

Comment: “so the remote repo can have uncommitted local changes” No it can’t. If they are not committed they are not in the repo.

Comment: @matt I guess we use the word differently. What if I rephrase it: "Can I pull a remote Git repository and also get the uncommitted working changes associated with that repository?"

Comment: Not as part of a pull. What the remote gives you in a pull or fetch are commits. Commits and their names and contents are all that a remote has to give.

Comment: What about stashed changes in the remote?

Comment: Nope, stashed changes fall in the same category as the working copy. They will not be returned by a pull / fetch

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot pull uncommitted changes. This would be a great use-case for a branch. Branch off, commit the work, and then it can be pulled. When you are happy with the changes merge the new branch into the original.